# mean line to interaction plot

Tags: r, interaction

Does anyone know how to add mean line on interaction plot? My code goes like this:

```
#interaction plot
with(datascen_2minBL, interaction.plot(scenario, role, cw2_sum_ampl_per_min, xlab = "baselines", ylab = "2min sumAmplPerMin"))
```

I have multiple responses from each participant measured at different time points. Each participant has different roles "AO", "RO", "TO" and "AO". My interaction lines represent means per each role. Now I would like to add grand mean line. How could I achieve that?
THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `lines`, the `mean` without the interaction variable using `tapply` should give you the needed values. *Example:*

```
with(ToothGrowth, interaction.plot(dose, supp, len, fixed=TRUE, legend=F))
lines(with(ToothGrowth, tapply(len, dose, mean)), col=2)
legend("topleft", lty=1:2, col=c(1, 1, 2), legend=c("OJ", "VC", "grand mean"), 
       title="supp", bty="n", cex=.9)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh I´m sorry, I did not think through what I was saying. I meant mean for those two lines. Ie. a line that runs between the two lines; an average of them two.

Comment: I was busy with my work, so I just now had time to get back to this.

Comment: @timothy Welcome, happy to hear that!